# OCaml and functions and argv

Tags: ocaml

Here is the code:

```
open Printf

let n = int_of_string Sys.argv.(1)
let k = int_of_string Sys.argv.(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no call to `mountainsnumber` at the outermost level of this code. So if this is your complete code, it just computes values for `n` and `k`, and then defines some functions. This will produce no output, because the defined functions are never called.

If this is the problem you just need to add a call to `mountainsnumber` at the end. Something like this:

```
let () = mountainsnumber n k
```

**Update**

(Hmm, you have edited your post to remove all the content. So this comment doesn't make a lot of sense any longer.)